# Conditions for existence of a Moore-Penrose inverse

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $A$ be a (noncommutative) $*$-algebra, and think of $A$ like it were endomorphisms on a finite dimensional vector space.

A Moore-Penrose inverse for $a \in A$ is $b$ such that

1. $bab = b$.
2. $aba = a$.
3. $(ab)^* = ab$ ("$ab$ is Hermitian").
4. $(ba)^* = ba$ ("$ba$ is Hermitian").

What are sufficient conditions for a $*$-algebra to always have Moore-Penrose inverses? Ideally, I would like to hear about a sufficient and necessary condition, but such a nice condition may not exist.